# Is there a way to keep the splash screen as long as we need for the main screen to be ready?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

In other words, instead of fixed **15 seconds**, is there a way to, to tell it to stop showing when my async function is finished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a separate screen for **Splash screen**, you can simply `await` the `async` function you have and the use `Navigator.pushReplacement()` to open your **Main Screen**

### Example:

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return SplashScreenState();
  }
}

class SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    handleSplashscreen();
  }

  void handleSplashscreen() async {
    // Wait for async to complete
    await someAsyncFunction();
    // Open Main page
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage(user: null)));
  }

  Future<void> someAsyncFunction() async {
    // Do some Network or other stuff
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(child: Text("Loading...")),
    );
  }
}
```

If you are simply showing a loader in the same screen while async operation is being done, you can use a `FutureBuilder` as others suggested.

Or you can conditionally show **loader** and  **Main UI** using a boolean and `setState()`.

### Example:

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MainPageState();
  }
}

class MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  // Boolean to show/ hide loader
  bool isLoading = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    handleAsync();
  }

  void handleAsync() async {
    // Wait for async to complete
    await someAsyncFunction();
    // Open Main page
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  Future<void> someAsyncFunction() async {
    // Do some Network or other stuff
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Using isLoading to check whether async function is complete
    return isLoading
        ? Container(
            child: Center(child: Text("Loading...")),
          )
        : Container(
            child: Text("The Actual screen"),
          );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FutureBuilder` [from here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) in the page and show splash screen image when the data is not loaded.